# Shell function is working weird in excel vba

Tags: excel, vba, shell

I created a button and then put the shell function under the button. My codes is like:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Shell (ThisWorkbook.Path & "\ABC.exe")
End Sub
```

The .exe function is to read a .txt file from the same directory and write a new .txt file in the same directory.

However, when I pressed the button, the new .txt file was generated on the desktop, not the current directory. And also, it does not read the correct .txt file from the directory. I tried to put the .txt on Desktop and I found that the .exe can then read it correctly!

The .exe runs perfectly from file explorer. When I double clicked it, it can read and write the .txt in the same directory without any problems.

I know this question sounds weird, do anyone have any ideas about this problems? Any help will be appreciated, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved!
I used Chdir and Chdrive to indicate the default directory, the .exe is running perfectly now.
Thanks for the help anyway :)

Comment: I problem solved, mark a response (eventually yours) as the answer, instead of editing the title.

Answer (score 0):

Shell ("cmd /c " & ThisWorkbook.Path & "\ABC.exe")

Comment: Thanks for the help! But then run-time error '53' occurred, saying "File not found"

Comment: Runtime error '53': file not found" error  - are you sure this file exist? Also check that there are no spaces in ThisWorkbook.path

Comment: The file exist without any problems! I really don't know how the error comes out.

Comment: @user1906523 if your question is solved please mark the answer which satisfies you with the check mark :)

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
s = "cmd /c " & ThisWorkbook.Path & "\ABC.exe"
Debug.Print s
Shell (s)
```

maybe you have misspaced something